# webpack change path script

Tags: javascript, webpack, ejs

Recently, I managed to use `ejs-loader` with *Webpack 4*. But, I started to get trouble with the script tag that webpack create into index.html when it launch : `<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>`. His `src` is not right because if we look my build I need `src="/dist/main.js"` :

```
node_modules/
dist/
  index.html
  main.js
publics/
src/
views/
server.js
package.json
webpack.config.js
```

What I need to add into my `webpack.congfig.js` to create a src like I want ?

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',

    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.ejs$/,
                use: ['ejs-loader']
            }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './views/pages/index.ejs'})
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    output: {
        publicPath: '/dist/' // <---- this
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.ejs$/,
                use: ['ejs-loader']
            }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './views/pages/index.ejs'})
    ]
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to mask as a solution!